# How to replicate my simulation study

Tags: r, replication, simulation, montecarlo

I am a beginner in R and I am doing a simulation study which I managed to produce one sample what I want to do.
However, I have no idea how I should replicate what I did.

Here is the program I wrote so far:

```
I <- 500       # number of observations
J <- 18        # total number of items
K <- 6         # number of testlets
JK <-3         # number of items within a testlet
response <- matrix(0, I, J)  # null binary (0, 1) response matrix 
unit <- matrix(1, JK, 1)     # unit vector

set.seed(1234)

# Multidimensional 3-pl model
pij <- function(a,b,c,theta,gamma) {c+(1-c)*(1/(1+exp(-1.7*a*(theta-b-gamma))))}

# Assigning a and b parameter values
a <- c(.8,.9,.7,.8,.9,.7,.8,.9,.7,.8,.9,.7,.8,.9,.7,.8,.9,.7)
b <-c(1,0,-1.5,1,0,-1.5,1,0,-1.5,1,0,-1.5,1,0,-1.5,1,0,-1.5)
# Assigning c-parameter, each 3 items (c-parameter & testlet effect)
#(small&small, small&large, large&small, large&large, mixed&small, mixed&large)
c <- c(.2,.2,.2,.2,.2,.2,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.2,.33,.5,.2,.33,.5)    

theta <- rnorm(I, 0, 1)   # random sampling theta-values from normal dist. M=0, SD=1

gamma1 <- rnorm(I, 0, .2)  # small testlet effect: random sampling gamma from normal dist. M=0, SD=.2
gamma2 <- rnorm(I, 0, 1)   # large testlet effect: random sampling gamma from normal dist. M=0, SD=1
gamma3 <- rnorm(I, 0, .2)  # small testlet effect: random sampling gamma from normal dist. M=0, SD=.2
gamma4 <- rnorm(I, 0, 1)   # large testlet effect: random sampling gamma from normal dist. M=0, SD=1
gamma5 <- rnorm(I, 0, .2)  # small testlet effect: random sampling gamma from normal dist. M=0, SD=.2
gamma6 <- rnorm(I, 0, 1)   # large testlet effect: random sampling gamma from normal dist. M=0, SD=1

# implementing that the testlet effect is same for the items within a testlet
gamma1T <- gamma1 %*% t(unit)
gamma2T <- gamma2 %*% t(unit)
gamma3T <- gamma3 %*% t(unit)
gamma4T <- gamma4 %*% t(unit)
gamma5T <- gamma5 %*% t(unit)
gamma6T <- gamma6 %*% t(unit)

gammaT <- matrix(c(gamma1T, gamma2T, gamma3T, gamma4T, gamma5T, gamma6T), I, J)  # getting all the gammas together in a large matrix

# Generating data using the information above
for(i in 1:I) {
  for(j in 1:J) {
    response[i, j] <- ifelse(pij(a=a[j], b=b[j], c=c[j], theta=theta[i], gamma=gammaT[i,j]) < runif(1), 0, 1)
  }
}
```

Thus, I get a data set "response". 
What I want to do is to replicate this and get say, 1000 "response" data sets.
I think this can be done by replicating the random sampling for "theta" and "gamma", but I do not have an idea to actually do this.

Many, many thanks in advance,

Hanjoe.

Answer (score 4):

The advice of Stedy is reasonable, apart from one thing: **DON'T** increment the seed in the for loop.

As fas as I understand Stedy's suggestion, `set.seed(i)` would be called within the `for` loop for each simulation, with `i` being incremented in each iteration. This strategy is [known](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1276927.1276928) to introduce (potentially large) bias due to correlations among the generated sequences.

Instead, **set the seed once** at the beginning, i.e. before the `for` loop. For example, you could use the current Unix time as a seed, or read one from a file with random numbers (e.g. from [random.org](http://random.org)). Also, make sure to store the seed with your results, e.g. print it to a log file. If you want to reproduce the *exact* results of a previous set of replications again, you just have to set the corresponding seed.

If you want others to be able to exactly replicate your results, you should also specify the R version (and maybe the operating system) you used (as the RNG implementations may vary).

As an aside, simulation replication is an [embarassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarassingly_parallel) task, i.e. you can easily execute the replications in parallel if you have a multi-core machine (e.g. with [rparallel](http://www.rparallel.org/)). In this case, however, extra care regarding random numbers is necessary (e.g. see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0167-8191%2802%2900163-1)).

Comment: Interesting answer and good to know for future use of set.seed

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is not really widely known and also applies to most other RNGs out there (see the linked paper).

Answer (score 1):

I would take the local variables and make them into a function.  Then make a `for()` loop, call the function and increment `set.seed()` by one each time the function is called for the length of the `for()` loop.

Comment: Hi Stedy, thank you for the advise. Can you be a little bit more explicit when you say make the local variables into a function?